# Enable users to add more textbox fields to a form if they need to enter more

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I am building an MS Access database which handles our restaurants food purchasing, inventory, and menu item pricing. Part of the pricing calculation is to allow our cooks to enter recipes that contain the amounts of each food item used, and then the reports will look in the tables for food purchases and determine how much that menu item should cost based on the amounts used.

The table relationships are as follows:
[image]

So basically, each record in the [Recipes] table can have any number of [Ingredients] that are associated with that recipe. Each of those [Ingredients] is an object in [Food items].

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make a form for the recipe entry that will start out with 5 ingredients on the default form (i.e. 3 fields for each ingredient - one for the food item, one for the serving unit, and one for the # serving units used). But if a recipe has more than 5 ingredients, I want the users to be able to click something that says "Add another ingredient" that will create the textboxes for them to enter info for another ingredient.

Does anyone have information on how to go about doing this right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to structure your data so that each recipe record is linked to several ingredient records and each ingredient record is linked to a food item.

Then for each recipe you can add a new ingredient record and select which food item this ingredient contains. The ingredient record would also have fields for the serving unit and number of units.

Your data entry form would the have the recipe details on the main form and then a subform containing the list of ingredients. Your users can then add as many ingredients as required to the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have the recipe entry form have a subform for gathering ingredients: that way the users will be able to add a new row just by clicking on the standard 'star' for a new record, and the scroll bars are available by default.